# Static method to return the class and method it's actually used in

Tags: php

**Here is what I want to do :** I want to be able to debug my application nice and clean.

I've got this **static html::debug($var)** that I would want to **return the class and method it's used in** plus the variable name and its contents, **without knowing the name of the class it will be used in in advance.**

If I use **_*CLASS*_** or **getClass()** it returns the class HTML where it's been instantiated. I would like to return the class and method where it's been used.

*An example, it's not the actual code:*

```
class HTML
{
    static function debug($var)  {
            echo "<pre style=\"border: 1px solid #000; height: {9em};
                  overflow: auto; margin: 0.5em;\">"; 

            echo '<b><u><font color = brown> In '.__CLASS__.'</u> : </font></b>';
```

**or**

```
            echo '<b><u><font color = brown> In '.get_class($this).'</u> : </font></b>';
            var_dump($var);    
            echo "</pre>\n";
     }
}

Class MyClass
{
      function myMethod()   {
      $variable = 'my_temp_var';
      html::debug($variable);
      }
}
```

There you go, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do, and it's a sign that you are going the wrong way. A method should never need to know who called it; if it needs to vary its behavior then tell it how using arguments.

OK, I lied: technically it *is* possible through [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php), but that is a solution that should never be used in production code. But it seems that in your case that's exactly what you want: to print debugging information.

Answer (score 0):

How about sending as an extra parameter to debug method the calling class? Like:

```
html::debug($variable,$this);
```

then use `get_class($classReceived)`

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing this would be to use the callstack. I don't think there's anything else natively in PHP to do what you want? Might be wrong.

So if you were to use something like..

```
$calledFrom = debug_backtrace( DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT, 1 );
```

This will give you an array of the previous callstack entry. It's really not ideal for a number of reasons, but it'll solve your problem.

Note: The last param is the limit, and I beleive this is 5.4 only. Remove if you're using a version older than this.

See here for full docs and the output: http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php